# Get JsonResult within ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult, jsonresult

My data is being generated at a JsonResult which output is below.

```
public JsonResult SampleAAA(Guid xxxxx){
    
    //Code ...

    return Json(new
    {
        success = true,
        listA,
        listB,
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

From an ActionResult I need to call that JsonResult and get those lists.

```
public ActionResult SampleBBB(Guid xxxxx){

    var result = SampleAAA(xxxx);
    //How can I access 'listA' and 'listB' ?

    //Other code ...

    Return View();
}
```

How can I access those lists? I do see `result.Data` content, but I can't reach those lists to continue my code at Visual Studio.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling one action from another. Instead, move the code that generates those values into a method both of your actions can call.

Comment: The ideia here is: ActionResult generates the first version of ```View()```, and then user can navigate at the frontend with ```AJAX``` requests being sent to mentioned JsonResult. Thats why ActionResult should call JsonResult

Comment: The original jsonresult is long gone, after you have sent the first request back to the client.

Comment: @PoulBak Sure, the point is that JsonResult code is going to work again and again, no need to call everything else the ActionResult does

Comment: You can use the `Value` property of `JsonResult`, but I would still advice you to create a method that returns the object instead of json. Json is not nice to 'mess with' to get data, unless its deserialized.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Both ```result.Value``` and ```result.Data.Value``` don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies. After more research I've managed to solve with the code below.

```
public ActionResult SampleBBB(Guid xxxxx){

    var result = SampleAAA(xxxx);

    //Steps to have access to those information:
    string stringJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result.Data);
    var resultString = JObject.Parse(stringJson);
    var outputA = resultString["listA"].Value<string>();

    //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
 var result = SampleAAA(xxxx);

 var jsonObject = (JObject)result.Value;

 bool success =  (bool)jsonObject["success"];
```

and it's much better to use JsonResult

```
return new JsonResult(new
    {
        success = true,
        listA,
        listB,
    });
```

Comment: Didn't compile. At second line (didn't include third line), Visual Studio error was: Cannot convert type 'method' to 'JObject'

Answer (score 0):

Using .Net 5+ you can do this:

```
using System.Text.Json;

var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(YOUR_JSON);
var property = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("ListA");
```